# How to use <object> tag to display SVG with percentage width and height

Tags: html, css, svg

I originally had a set of PNGs which I could then display with the `<img>` and add a css `width` property set to `60%`. This allows the page to be responsive and correctly display on all displays.

I am now wanting to upgrade these PNGs to SVGs to have better quality. The problem is that within the SVGs, I ideally need to use other external SVGs to make sure the SVG isn't to big. In the `<img>` element

- if I set the `src` to the SVG, external resources can't be fetched.
- So instead, I've tried to use the `<obejct>` tag which allows the SVGs to use external resources. But now when I add css `width` property, it doesn't do anything.

Is it possible to have percentage widths on the `<object>` tag or use a different tag that allows for external resources.

An example of an image that doesn't work is: https://gitlab.com/frodobot/website/-/blob/dnh/new_command_pictures/public/static/img/commands/commandImageBase.svg#L59 (you might have to click on source to see the SVG code)

Comment: This should be helpful https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

Comment: I don't think any of these appear to work because they don't allow external resources

Answer (score 0):

`img` and `object` works exactly the same way. For both it's possible to use external media, it just must be linked correctly. You can set the size with CSS.

```css
img {
width: 200px;
}

object {
width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/Flat_tick_icon.svg">

<object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/Flat_tick_icon.svg"></object>
```

Comment: Sorry, for not making it clear but by external media, I mean external images within another SVG. For example, by using the <image> tag in svg

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/frodobot/website/-/blob/dnh/new_command_pictures/public/static/img/commands/commandImageBase.svg#L59 (you might have to click on source to see the SVG code)